# Drag and Drop events with dataTransfer not works in mobile view

Tags: javascript, html, angular, mobile, drag-and-drop

I'm using drag & drop events in angular with dataTransfer as below.

**html file:**

```
<div (dragstart)="dragStartHandler($event)" (dragend)="dragEndHandler($event)"></div>
<div (dragleave)="onDragLeave($event)" (drop)="onDrop($event)"></div>
```

**ts file:**

```js
dragStartHandler(event) {
        event.dataTransfer.setData("text", "data to transfer");
}

dragEndHandler(event) {
        //other css related stuff
}

onDragLeave(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();

    //other css related stuff
} 
  
onDrop(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();

    let data = event.dataTransfer.getData("text");
}
```

It is working fine in desktop. But **it not works in any mobile view/device**. I heard about touch events for mobile devices but I am unable to transfer data through it. so is there any way to achieve this same functionality in mobile view with angular??